# Any support for the Honor View 10?

Tags: arcore

Hello I was wishing to use ARcore on my Honor View 10 but ARcore is not supported? I was wondering whether it is in the plan to make it supported?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below details.

1. except of Android (China) below version could be used with ARCore.
   Honor 8X, Honor 10
   Honor View 10 Lite
2. In Android (China)
   Honor 10
   Honor Magic 2

hope it help.
thanks.

Comment: Ah so because I ordered my Honor phone from the supplier in China I can't use ARcore